# missing USB driver ttyACM0

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb

I am trying to connect a USB-GPIO module to my Asus C300s  Chromebook that now runs Lubuntu 16.04 (Xanial).

The GPIO manufacturer claims that every Linux distribution comes with a ttyacm0/1/2 USB  driver,  but I see none in /dev

Can anyone please instruct me where to find and how to install this missing driver?

Comment: Every Linux does come with support for `/dev/ttyACM<number>` and `/dev/ttyUSB<number>`. With Arduino and Raspberry Pi that I connect via either USB or UART cable, I've never had to install any drivers. You might be doing something wrong. Check the module's manual, if you have one.

Comment: Serge, thank you. I now realized that my Ubuntu (running on a chroot in a Chromebook)  did not at all respond to  plugging the USB connector into the computer.  There must be another problem that prevents the computer from recognizing a newly plugged USB device.    Does anyone have any idea how to continue from here?